# Why does std cin work only when used with int variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use std::cin after a while.

#### Using `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char data;
std::cin >> std::dec >> data;
```

Whatever `std::dec` is used or not, I get the first ASCII character I type.
If I type `12`, data is `0x31` not `12`. Why can't it parse number until `255` to be stored in a `char`?

```
int data;
std::cin >> std::dec >> data;
```

gives **correctly** `data=12/0xC` not `0x31`

- Why?

#### Using `char[N]` with `std::hex`

```
char data[128];
std::cin >> std::hex >> data;
```

Also gets the ASCII characters instead of the hexadecimal.

- Writting `0x010203040506...` data is `0xFFFFFFFFF..`.
- Isn't `std::cin>>std::hex` able to parse the string I type into hexadecimal automatically?

Comment: If it worked like you're assuming, how would you read "12" as two separate digit characters?

Comment: I expected `std::hex/dec` to convert the `0x3132 / "12"` to binary `12=0xC`...

Comment: This is a old issue in stream i/o. You can try ```uint8_t i=60; cout << i;``` and it will print a character with corresponding ASCII. That's because stream io operators treat char types differently, they are not considered number.

Comment: C++20 is going to solve it by providing a new type (char8_t)

Comment: @LIUQingyuan Thanks, I already stopped using cout (for {fmt}) but I can't find an alternative to `cin`...

Comment: @Alexis Read the dex number in as string and convert it to integer later on. Another annoying issue in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short:

- `cin >> charVar` scans a single character from `stdin`
- `cin >> intVar` scans characters from `stdin` until a non-numeric character is entered

Explaining your observation:

A `char` variable can store a single ASCII character.

When you type `12`, only the character `1` is scanned.

The ASCII code of the character `1` is `0x31`.

Comment: `std::cin >> std::dec >> intVar;` gives me binary, not the ASCII. It converts properly my input to decimal even though I write more than 4 characters/digits.

Comment: "as many characters from stdin until a new-line character is entered" - No, that's wrong. It scans until it can't parse a number anymore.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: ahhh, that's correct, thanks; I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

`std::dec` and `std::hex` affect the format of integers.

But as far as the streaming operators are concerned, `char` and its variants (including `uint8_t` aren't integers, they're single characters. They will always read a single character, and never parse an integer.

That's just how these functions are defined. There is no way around it. If you want an integer with a limited range, first read into an `int` (or other integer type that is not a `char` variant), and then range-check afterwards. You can, if you want, cast it to a small type afterwards, but you probably shouldn't. `char` types are awkward to work with numerically.

Similarly, reading into an array of `char` reads a string. (Also, never do that without using `setw()` to limit the length to fit in the buffer you have. Better yet, use `std::string` instead.) That's just how it's defined.

Comment: That's to do hardware, not sure I can use `std::string` for contiguous raw buffer. Especially my goal is to convert the string I type to be considered as `hex`.

Comment: Use int to capture the number with `cin`, but there is no conversion to hex. It is **when you print** the number that you ask to print it in hex form by passing `std::hex` to `std::cout`.

Comment: And if you want to read a long string of hex digits, you can read them either into a string (or char array), or repeatedly into a pair of chars, and then do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to see the effect of a manipulator like `std::hex` while obtaining input with `std::cin`, one could try with an integer variable as follows,

```
int test_hex;
std::cin >> std::hex >> test_hex;
```

If `0x12` is entered as input, the integer value `18` is stored in the integer variable `test_hex`. We can see that `std::hex` has had its effect in an input context.

On the other hand, if `0x12` is entered in the following case, the string `"0x12"` is written into the character array `data`. Note: the points by Sebastian Redl about the size of the input not exceeding the size of the character array and about rather using `std::string` should be kept in mind.

```
char data[128];
std::cin >> std::hex >> data;
```

Thus, the effect of an I/O manipulator is very much dependent on the type of the variable involved.